# RestKit: NSManagedObject embedded in NSObject

Tags: ios, restkit

`Book` is a plain `NSObject`, while `Author` is a `NSManagedObject`, and i am mapping `Book#author` to `Author` in the `Book.objectMapping`, the problem is i am embedding a managed object into a normal object, is it possible that RestKit will map the embedded `author` into a CoreData object?

```
//Book.m
+ (RKObjectMapping *)objectMapping {
        RKObjectMapping *mapping = [RKObjectMapping mappingForClass:[Book class]];
        mapping.rootKeyPath = @"book";
       [mapping mapKeyPathsToAttributes:@"book_id", @"bookID",
                                        @"author_id", @"authorID", nil];

       [mapping mapKeyPath:@"author"
            toRelationship:@"author"
               withMapping:[Author objectMapping]];
}
```

Comment: @PauldeLange, no, it doesn't work, when i tried to access the `author` via the property, it always gives me this:
`(Author *) $1 = 0x080afef0 <Author: 0x80afef0> (entity: Author; id: 0x80ab740 <x-coredata://D76EF1FD-1727-449A-8D17-AC2C54200B3F/Author/p4> ; data: <fault>)`

Comment: What you report as the property looks correct? What is the problem?

Comment: Could you post the code for [Author objectMapping]? I'm curious how you're doing those mappings without passing in a reference to a RKObjectMappingProvider.

Answer (score 0):

One thing to check is that you associated the class to the entity in your Core Data Model. Pull up the Entity Inspector and make sure you set the Class to Author. If you don't set the class it'll end up loading your objects as NSManagedObjects.